# jQuery Mobile NavBar with data-position="fixed" floats to middle

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navbar

[image]

Using the data-position="fixed" attribute with jQuery mobile but it still floats to the middle when pages are changed. Anyone have this problem before?

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="nav">        
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom">
        <ul>
            <li><a data-transition="fade" href="#home" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active">Map</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="fade" href="#near" data-icon="search">Near</a></li>
            <li><a data-transition="fade" href="#account"  data-icon="star">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

---

UPDATE

I found something about issues with fixed position Nav on Android 2.2/2.3.

I'm using the Ripple Emulator to test the app right now, so I'm not sure if it's implementing Android 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem relates to the Ripple emulator. Once loaded onto an Android, iOS, BlackBerry, or Windows Device the problem no longer occurs.